# Changing Enterprise Architect Default Check In Comment

Tags: version-control, enterprise-architect

In Sparx Enterprise Architect, when I check in a package that is under version control it prompts me to enter a comment and provides a default in the format "Check-in: [date] [time]". How can I change this comment template?

Comment: I looked for the same feature. It's not documented in the user guide http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/versioncontrol.html. A search in all text files under "program files/Sparx" and "documents and settings" produced no result...

Answer (score 0):

Currently (V9 and below), it is not possible to change this setting.