# Enterprise Architect: Modify default check in comment

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Sparx Enterprise Architect, when I check in a package that is under version control it prompts me to enter a comment and provides a default in the format "Check-in: [date] [time]". How can I change this comment template?

I would like to have it say "Check-in: [Package-name]"

Note: This question was asked 7 years ago without a sufficient answer due to old version of Enterprise Architect without such capability: [Changing Enterprise Architect Default Check In Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437895/changing-enterprise-architect-default-check-in-comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The only way is to write your own script that issues a check-in command. This also is not easily possible since EA does not offer an API for it's version control interface. It is possible to emulate EA's action during a check-in (since it just calls the VC provider's API and sets a couple of flags in its database). But that's tedious, error prone and not likely to be supported by anyone except yourself. You might send in a feature request. But don't be surprised if you don't see any response within the next 7 years :-/